# Angular 5 : How can i save a user with a BLOB avatar

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm a newbie on Angular and i want to save a new user with an avatar, so how can i pass the Blob value of the avatar to my user Model so i can save it properly?

This is my code :

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" value="{{image}}" id="avatar" ngModel name="avatar" #avatar="ngModel"/>
```

**Typescript**

```
image:any;

onSelectFile(event) {
  var reader ;
  reader = new FileReader;
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    console.log(reader.result);
    this.image = reader.result;
    console.log(this.image);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

The error i get when saving the user:

```
{"timestamp":"2018-11-24T13:29:13.222+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]` from String \"\\fakepath\\IMG_20180808_023905.jpg\": Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character ':' (code 0x3a) in base64 content; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]` from String \"\\fakepath\\IMG_20180808_023905.jpg\": Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character ':' (code 0x3a) in base64 content\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 134] (through reference chain: org.vi.entities.User[\"avatar\"])","path":"/users"}
```

PS: the type of avatar field in user table is longblob

Answer (score 1):

I don't encourage you to save images as blobs in the database, it's better to save just the name of the avatar and get the image to show after.

if you are interested in trying that I think [this tutorial](https://brianflove.com/2017/11/02/angular-http-client-blob/) is good for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
onSelectFile(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader;
    reader.onload = this.handle.bind(this); 
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
}

handle(readerEvt: any) {

   let bytes = new Uint8Array(readerEvt.target.result);
   for (let index = 0; index < bytes.byteLength; index++) {
       this.image += String.fromCharCode(bytes[index]);
    }
 }
```

it is better idea to write images as text in database and send base64 string to server.
Then your function should look like this:

```
handle(readerEvt: any) {

   let bytes = new Uint8Array(readerEvt.target.result);
   let binaryText = ''; 
   for (let index = 0; index < bytes.byteLength; index++) {
       let binaryText += String.fromCharCode(bytes[index]);
    }
   this.image = btoa(binaryText);
 }
```

Comment: this is not good practice in case of large files.
for large files put files on server using form data